# Eigenvectors of 2x2 matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider matrices,

$ P = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 5 & 2 \\\end{pmatrix}$

$ D = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \\\end{pmatrix}$

defined as $ A = PDP^{-1} $. The solutions state that the eigenvectors of $A$ can be found without calculation as,

$ v_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\\end{pmatrix}$

$ v_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\\end{pmatrix}$

I can find the above vectors using the standard method of finding eigenvalues and then equating to a zero vector, but what I would like to understand is how the vectors can be found WITHOUT any calculations?
Thank you.

Comment: What are the eigenvectors of a diagonal matrix? If $A=PDP^{-1}$ the what does $D$ equal?

Comment: Are we to assume that the nonzero elements of $D$ are the eigenvalues of the matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have $A=PDP^{-1}$, then we have

$$AP=PD$$

Which is

$$A\begin{bmatrix}v_1 & v_2 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}d_1 v_1 & d_2v_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}Av_1 & Av_2 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}d_1 v_1 & d_2v_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Hence columns of $P$ consists of the eigenvectors.